# How to retrieve the value of a text box and use it in the same page without redirecting to a next page in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

I am running the below code in JSP. I am facing problem in retrieving a value ..  say from a drop down list and then use/display that value in the same page where the drop down is present but   **WITHOUT**  redirecting to a next page.

```
<div class="form-row"> 
    <label>
        <span>Department Name</span> 
        <select name="s1">
            <option>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
            <option>C</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>
<input type=text value="">
```

When I select anything from the list, the value should be retrieved without going to the next page. It should be retrieved in the same page and displayed in the text box.

WITHOUT Ajax, how can it be done? Can someone help me please ...?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're best bet is to use Javascript. As JSP is a server side language, it is processed before the page is even sent to the user. In order to get information that information without sending another request to the server, you will need to use a client-side scripting language (aka Javascript).

Comment: I think I understand what you want.. Such as... this...? If I select A it should display the vlaue A or is it that if I select A it should display List A?

Comment: @ShamSUP  Is there any other way other than javascript ? And if done with javascript how to do it? can you show an example ?

Comment: Not without submitting the value to the server (a la submitting a form with the value)

Comment: @Matt  If I select A from the list, then it should display just  "A" in the text box for example.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, we will have to use JavaScript then. As ShamSUP said, JSP is a server-side language while JavaScript is user-side language. Google for more understanding on that.

The code would be this.

```
<div class="form-row"> 
            <label>
                <span>Department Name</span> 
                <select name="s1" onChange="displayDropValue()">
            <option>A</option>
             <option>B</option>
             <option>C</option>
          </select>
           </label>
        </div>

<input name="o1" type=text value="">

<script>
function displayDropValue() {
  dropdownValue = document.getElementsByName("s1")[0].value; //Get dropdown value by looking for the name attribute. Since this function returns as array we have to use [] to say first array element
  document.getElementsByName("o1")[0].value = dropdownValue;
}
</script>
```

I didn't test the code, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use javascript in order to get the effect that you want. Because JSP is a server-side scripting language, it will not be able to "see" what the user is selecting from the field unless the value is submitted to the server somehow for processing, such as a form submission.

Javascript is a client-side scripting language, which means it can be processed in the user's web browser, and therefore can "see" what the user has done with anything on the page. To achieve the effect you're looking for, the amount of javascript required is minimal.

First, you will have to find a way to specify which text input you want to populate. The easiest way to do this is to add an `id` to it.

```
<input type="text" id="textfield" value="">
```

After doing that, we need to bind an event handler to listen for when the `select` box's value changes, and get that value and put it into the text field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// get the select element, then bind a function to the change event
document.querySelector('select[name=s1]').onchange = function(){
    // get the text field, and set it's value to the value of the select box
    document.getElementById('textfield').value = document.querySelector('select[name=s1]').value;
}
</script>
```

Now you just take that code and put it into either the `head` or the end of the `body` in your html.